# Remove border line on groupbox WPF

Tags: wpf

is there a way to remove the border line on group box or just make it transparent color?? i couldn't find a way to solve it. and i already spend a lot of hours solving this problem

i have tried to include this but it seems not working

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:NumberFormatter x:Key="myNumberFormatter">
    </local:NumberFormatter>
    <local:FontColorChanger x:Key="myColorChanger">
    </local:FontColorChanger>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Save Filter" Name="SaveFilterContext" Click="SaveContext_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Reset List" Name="ResetContext" Click="ResetContext_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Refresh List" Name="RefreshListContext" Click="RefreshListContext_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ListSearchContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Symbols" Name="SymbolsContext"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TransparentButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tabVwDtlDescContentTemplate">
        <dx:MeasurePixelSnapper Margin="5,5,10,10"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="defaultDataRowTemplateModified">
        <Grid MaxHeight="2500">
            <Expander x:Name="expander" Foreground="Black" IsExpanded="{Binding Path=RowState.(local:FOREXWatch.Expanded)}" ExpandDirection="Down" Grid.Row="1">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource {dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=DataRowTemplate}}" Margin="-25,0,0,0"/>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.IsEnabled>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:MyConverterExpanderState/>
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding Path="(dxg:GridControl.ActiveView)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                        <Binding Path="RowHandle.Value" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Expander.IsEnabled>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="busyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value=".5,.5" />
                        </Style>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Canvas Width="64" Height="64">
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="24">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="top" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="6">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-45" />
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="topLeft" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="24" Width="16" Height="8">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="left" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="34">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="bottomLeft" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="40">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="bottom" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="34">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-45" />
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="bottomRight" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="24" Canvas.Left="38" Width="16" Height="8">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="right" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="6">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="topRight" Color="#DFDFDF" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Canvas>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:1.6">
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="top"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="topRight"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.2"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="right"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bottomRight"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.6"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bottom"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.8"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bottomLeft"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:1"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="left"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:1.2"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="topLeft"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="#606060"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:1.4"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0" />

                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="top"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.1"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="topRight"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.3"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="right"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bottomRight"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.7"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bottom"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.9"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bottomLeft"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:1.1"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="left"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:1.3"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="topLeft"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:1.5"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="2500">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="255*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="160"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <controls:EditComboBox x:Name="m_FindSymbol" Width="150" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" IsEnabled="False" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Name="cleartextimg" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" Width="25" Source="/MarketWatch;component/Images/edit_clear.png" ToolTip="Erase text." MouseDown="cleartextimg_MouseDown" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Button Name="btnAddSymbol" Width="14" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" ToolTip="Click to add symbol to Market Watch" Click="btnAddSymbol_Click" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}" IsEnabled="False" Cursor="Hand">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/MarketWatch;component/Images/addSymbol.png" Width="10" Height="14"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Name="UpdateGrid" Grid.Row="1" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" MaxWidth="110"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" MinWidth="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Last Updated : " Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,0,0" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0" Name="labelLastUpdatedBanner" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                <Label Content=" " Grid.Column="1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,4,0" Foreground="White" Name="labelUpdatedDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Margin="0,45,0,0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">            
            <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="70"/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <dxg:GridControl BorderThickness="0" Margin="-12,-12,-12,-12" AutoPopulateColumns="True" Grid.Row="0" Name="dgForex" Visibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ContextMenu="{StaticResource DataGridContextMenu}"  >
                    <dxg:GridControl.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="BidCellStyle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=CellStyle}}"
                   TargetType="dxg:CellContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.StatusBid, Converter={StaticResource myColorChanger}}"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="AskCellStyle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=CellStyle}}"
                   TargetType="dxg:CellContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.StatusAsk, Converter={StaticResource myColorChanger}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
                    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Name="colSymbol" Header="Symbol" Tag="Symbol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quote.Symbol}" Width="100" MinWidth="75" AllowMoving="False"/>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Name="colBid" Header="Bid" Tag="Bid" Width="70" MinWidth="70" CellStyle="{StaticResource BidCellStyle}" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right" AllowResizing="False" AllowMoving="False">
                            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                <dxe:TextEditSettings  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
                                </dxe:TextEditSettings>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNumberFormatter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Quote.Bid"></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="Quote.Digits"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Name="colAsk" Header="Ask" Tag="Ask" Width="70" MinWidth="70" CellStyle="{StaticResource AskCellStyle}" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right" AllowResizing="False" AllowMoving="False">
                            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings >
                                <dxe:TextEditSettings HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNumberFormatter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Quote.Ask"></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="Quote.Digits"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                        <dxg:GridColumn Name="colDigits" Header="Digits" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quote.Digits}" Width="50" MinWidth="50" AllowMoving="False" Visible="False" Tag="Digits"/>
                        <dxg:GridColumn FixedWidth="True" Header="" Tag="Options" Width="18" MinWidth="18" AllowFocus="False" AllowResizing="False" AllowMoving="False" Fixed="Right">
                            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Button Name="btnRemove" Margin="0,3,0,0" FontSize="10" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" Click="btnRemove_Click" Width="14" MinWidth="14" ToolTip="Click to remove symbol from Market Watch" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}" Cursor="Hand">
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <Image Source="/MarketWatch;component/Images/removeSymbol.png" Width="10" MinWidth="10" Height="14"/>
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>

                    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridControl.View>
                        <dxg:TableView Name="tableView" ShowVerticalLines="False" AutoWidth="True" 
                                       ShowTotalSummary="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowIndicator="False" 
                                       NavigationStyle="Row" VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Auto" AllowColumnFiltering="False">
                            <dxg:TableView.ColumnMenuCustomizations>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.SortAscending}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.SortDescending}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.BestFit}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.BestFitColumns}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.ClearSorting}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.ColumnChooser}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.FilterEditor}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.SortDescending}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.ClearFilter}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.SearchPanel}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.GroupColumn}"/>
                                <dxb:RemoveBarItemAndLinkAction ItemName="{x:Static dxg:DefaultColumnMenuItemNames.GroupBox}"/>
                                <dxb:BarCheckItem Name="chkSymbol" Content="Symbol" IsChecked="True" CheckedChanged="chkSymbol_CheckedChanged"/>
                                <dxb:BarCheckItem Name="chkBid" Content="Bid" IsChecked="True" CheckedChanged="chkBid_CheckedChanged"/>
                                <dxb:BarCheckItem Name="chkAsk" Content="Ask" IsChecked="True" CheckedChanged="chkAsk_CheckedChanged"/>
                            </dxg:TableView.ColumnMenuCustomizations>
                        </dxg:TableView>
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>

                </dxg:GridControl>
                <Label Name="labelTradeSession" Margin="-12,15,-12,-15" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" Content="" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
        <dx:WaitIndicator Name="LoadingCtrl" DeferedVisibility="True" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="LightGray" Height="600" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ></dx:WaitIndicator>
    </Grid>
```

any ideas?

Comment: It's so hard to actually find the group box in your xaml , why did you post your entire UserControl ?

Comment: You don't need the border, you don't use the header, so the GroupBox does not add any value. Just use a Grid instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<GroupBox BorderThickness="0" />
```

I just wrote BorderThickness="0" on a GroupBox and then my borderline disapeared. If you still have the issue, it might have something to do with your other control, creating a border line. Since i don't have the full code, I can't really test it.

Comment: i think it was the grid next to the group box is there a way to remove the border of <grid>?

Comment: A grid does not have a border. It's just a container, you can't see, to hold your objects.

I think it is your GridControl that holds the border, because I can't really see where you should be setting one in your xaml.

You have a lot of styles as well. It could be in one of thoses as well I can't tell you from the code you are providing :)

Comment: i already edited the code part i already include all of the XAML code can you help me? you can see the full code above

Comment: <Style x:Key="busyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">

in this style you set Stroke="Black" and StrokeThickness="1".

Try to set them to Stroke="Transparent" or StrokeThickness="0"

Let me know if it worked :)